# How to change the sheet title color background?

Tags: phpspreadsheet

Trying to change the background color of the sheet title with PHPSpreadsheet.
No success with something like

```
`$sheet ->getTitle($sheet1)->getStyle()->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID);`
```

How would you address that specific cell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the argb value of color you want to set and write it in setARGB.

```
$cells='A1';
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($cells)->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('ffffff');
```

Answer (score 0):

$worksheet->getTabColor()->setRGB('FF0000');

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).